# Does Google Chrome required to enable push notification feature in Progressive Web App (PWA) for Desktop?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

From my research, it looks like we need, at least, Google Chrome installed on our Desktop computer to provide push notification feature.

1. So what if, our client doesn’t install Google Chrome, but has Microsoft Edge, or Firefox, or even Safari instead?
2. Would the push feature ready to be used if user install PWA from other PWA-supported web browser except Google Chrome?

I check the availability of Push API on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api) but still not clear about this.

Comment: Google chrome supports almost all the features that PWA provides, while other browsers are not fully supported PWA, so Google Chrome is good recommendation for PWA
You can get more specification in this [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification]

Comment: @AndroidPlayer_Shree Thank you. So does this mean we have to tell user to install PWA via Google Chrome instead other web browser? Is it necessary to force PWA install via Chrome?

Comment: Yes, because Google Chrome supports all the PWA features also you can see Browser compatibility graph in link that i provided in previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Safari is the only browser not supporting native push. You have to run your own cloud-side push service to handle communicating to the different browsers and operating systems.
Chrome, FireFox, Edge (old & new) all support native push notifications.
Not sure if this article will help or not, https://love2dev.com/pwa/push-notifications/